# Is it possible to combine two dataframes that sometimes has same or different row names

Tags: r, dataframe, merge

I have two data frames:

df1

```
Species               ID
Zanthoxylum bungeanum CNRhis0124310    
Zeuxine strateumatica CNRhis0124169   
Ziziphus jujuba       CNRhis0123820
```

df2

```
Species Source    
Zizania latifolia Huada   
Ziziphus jujuba   Huada
```

Which function can I use to make it look like this

```
Species ID Source    
Zanthoxylum bungeanum CNRhis0124310 NA    
Zeuxine strateumatica CNRhis0124169 NA    
Zizania latifolia NA Huada    
Ziziphus jujuba CNRhis0123820 Huada
```

So that I have all three columns, but the one with same species name get merged

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to SO. Did you read [How to join (merge) data frames (inner, outer, left, right)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1299871/how-to-join-merge-data-frames-inner-outer-left-right) ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to join (merge) data frames (inner, outer, left, right)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1299871/how-to-join-merge-data-frames-inner-outer-left-right)